# How to combine imageButton with TextView android

Tags: android, button, textview

I am developing a chemistry app.But I have a problem to create a periodic table which is fit to the device display size.But I am unable to do it.I tried with buttons.But it exceeding the space limit,I wanna to do this without using scroll view.Finally i choose image button with text view.Is it possible or there is an easy way for me.Please help

Comment: Can you paste screen shot or your layout code? Also eleborate how you want the view is it Image<space>Element name?

Answer (score 1):

Try ImageButton with TextView layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
   android:orientation="vertical" >  

   <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/img_button"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/img_button_height"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:adjustViewBounds="false"
      android:cropToPadding="false" 
      android:src="@drawable/your_image"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      //android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_button"
      //android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_button"

      //position your TextView inside ImageButton

      //android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      //android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:textSize="13sp"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:typeface="sans"
      android:text="" /> 




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an imageView not an imageButton and set the layout_width and layout_height as match_parent and set the src to your image of the periodic table(make sure to use src not background image as this will scale it correctly). If you need to add clicks to it you can do it programmatically the same way you would for an imageButton.